# Download and build third-party libraries with qmake

Tags: c++, git, qt, download, qmake

In **CMake** projects I used the [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) function to increase the portability and to decrease the storing unnecessary files in my own Git repository. This function among others can download, configure, build and install (to a specific location) an external library. I'm looking for the same functionality in **qmake** or something which is less "hacky" than my following trial.

Let's say I would like to use [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) in my Qt project (despite the Qt has its own) as follows:

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(Foo, FooTest) {
    qDebug() << "FooTest called...";
    ASSERT_TRUE(true);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

In the project file, I don't want to deal with how will I get the Google Test library, but counting on it:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++14 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

EP_BASE = $$OUT_PWD/3rdParty
include($$PWD/GTest.pri)

TARGET = FreeTesting
SOURCES += main.cpp
DEPENDPATH += $$EP_BASE/Install/gtest/include
INCLUDEPATH += $$EP_BASE/Install/gtest/include
LIBS += -L$$EP_BASE/Install/gtest/lib/ -lgtest -lgmock
```

And now here is my "hacky" `GTest.pri` file which downloads, builds and installs the libraries:

```
GTEST_V180 = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.0.tar.gz"

GTEST_DOWNLOAD_STEP = mkdir -p $$EP_BASE/Source/gtest; cd $$EP_BASE/Source/gtest; \
    curl -L $$GTEST_V180 | tar xzv --strip 1
GTEST_BUILD_STEP = mkdir -p $$EP_BASE/Build/gtest; cd $$EP_BASE/Build/gtest; \
    cmake $$EP_BASE/Source/gtest/ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$$EP_BASE/Install/gtest; \
    make
GTEST_INSTALL_STEP = mkdir -p $$EP_BASE/Install/gtest; cd $$EP_BASE/Build/gtest; \
    make install

gtest.target = googletest
gtest.commands = if [ ! -d $$EP_BASE/Install/gtest/lib ]; then
gtest.commands += $$GTEST_DOWNLOAD_STEP; $$GTEST_BUILD_STEP; $$GTEST_INSTALL_STEP;
gtest.commands += fi

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += gtest
PRE_TARGETDEPS += googletest
```

The reason I do not want to go further in this direction is that I don't want to rely on platform specific commands if there is built-in (or simply just better and more convenient) solution to the same problem.

Comment: Why don't you just use CMake?

Comment: @Velkan, I think using `qmake` for Qt projects inside Qt Creator is much convenient than `CMake`. Although for non-Qt projects I use `CMake`.

Comment: @Velkan, or you mention using `CMake` for downloading and building external libraries only?

Comment: Qt Creator opens CMake files fine. Qmake isn't a thing that will receive many future developments. So I use CMake for everything.

Comment: Upvoting this in 2019 since it is the first google search result in that direction and there is no definitive answer here

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bunch of options and settled on this snippet. The most interesting thing is that this solution replaces the qmake lame Makefile for the actual library's Makefile, integrating it into the project naturally.

```
include(../common.pri)

TEMPLATE = aux
LIBPCAP_URL = "http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.9.1.tar.gz"

tcpdump_libpcap.target = $$LIBPCAP
tcpdump_libpcap.depends = FORCE
tcpdump_libpcap.commands = \
    (wget -qO - $${LIBPCAP_URL} | tar --strip-components=1 -zxf -) && \
    (CC=\"$${QMAKE_CC}\" CFLAGS=\"$${QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE}\" ./configure \
    --host=$$NDK_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX --disable-bluetooth --disable-dbus --disable-shared --disable-usb) && \
    make $$tcpdump_libpcap.target

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += tcpdump_libpcap
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$tcpdump_libpcap.target

DISTFILES += CMakeLists.txt
```